# datatable loading image customization for ajax calls of column filtering

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using `primefaces datatable` with column filtering and global filtering too.
In our application we use custom `<p:ajaxStatus>` to trap all ajax calls and show `"Please wait.."` message until request is completed. It is blocking the complete UI.
This perfectly matches all the scenarios except the one i'm going to describe.
I want to do column specific filtering in datatable and if i enter some text an ajax call is fired and screen is blocked by custom ajax dialog box with message `"Please wait.."`
But i don't want this specific ajax calls to be trapped by global ajax. if we use attribute `global="false"` then it won't execute global ajax.
But in datatable, i can't give `global="false"` in `<p:column >` as a property.
In this case, i just want to show him a loading image at right bottom corner like all datatable filterings happening. check the following link how i want to implement.

[Data Table Filter demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml)

In the above example code is not provided. So how can i implement it ?
Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trap all ajax requests, we have defined `<p:ajaxStatus>` in main layout page.
Which is trapping all ajax requests.
So to overcome this, i have defined the same layout page in my included page and removed the customly defined `<p:ajaxStatus>` which blocks complete UI. The problematic code in layout page:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </div>
        <ui:insert name="dialog">
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
```

in included page we define content as

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Test Application</h1>
</ui:define>
```

**Solution**

```
 <p:ajaxStatus style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px">  
    <f:facet name="start">  
        <p:graphicImage name="loading.gif" library="images"></p:graphicImage>
    </f:facet>  

    <f:facet name="complete">  
        <h:outputText value="" />  
    </f:facet>  
</p:ajaxStatus>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content" >
                     <h1> Test Application </h1>
           </ui:insert>
       </div>
  </div>
```

So here any ajax request from this page will be trapped by custom  defined in this page. 
Which helped me a lot.
Hope it helps